# Arrows not displaying in Magnific Popup gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magnific-popup

I have the Magnific Popup working almost exactly how I would like it to but for some reason the arrows are not displaying in the gallery mode.

Instead are two empty boxes with what looks like a thin top border.

Looking at the CSS, I cannot find any reference to an image or inserting a character

i.e. inspecting the HTML in the webkit dev tools shows the default `<button>` markup but the tags are empty. The `.mfp-*` classes are present in the CSS but they do not refer to any image nor do the `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors insert any characters as `content`.

Should I have included some images in the project? If so what do I name them? I can find no reference to any images in the docs ...

Comment: Link to page with issue, please. There are no any images, all controls are CSS-based.

Comment: I'll see if I can upload it somewhere - I did find that using the `.css` file from the MP site and putting in a separate include works rather than compiling Sass file ... I suspect I have a problem with my build process ...

Comment: Hmm, I've recopied the Sass file from the MF website and it now works fine - I must have missed a couple of characters at the end or something. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Check the network tab and see if the images failed to load. If they did, it could either be a path issue in the css or the images were not added to the project.

Comment: Ah yeah that's a good point - there are no missed request which makes me think it might be a character rather than an image, there appear to be nothing in the CSS so it must be in the javascript - the font is the one that MP sets (Helvetica Neue etc.) which works on other sites ...